# AJAX Pagination in Codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Is it possible to use AJAX pagination in Codeigniter without editing the pagination libraries? Will editing the pagination libraries make life much easier?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to edit the pagination library. AJAX is all front-end bro. You simply make a view which displays your result listings and make another view which contains a div you'll populate with your listings view. Inside your results container you can load in ajax responses into the div using that other view.

Answer (score 0):

Use plugin [Jquery Pagintation](https://github.com/neotohin/CodeIgniter-Ajax-pagination-Library)

Add jquery before loading view.

```
//Define model function with limit
public function modelFunction($limit=0)
    {
        $this->db->select("....col_name....");
            //....................
            //.........
        $this->db->limit(10,$limit)->order_by('id', 'desc');
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();

    }



//Define controller function with limit
function controllerFunction($limit = 0)
    {
        $config['base_url'] = path_to_controllerFunction
        $config['total_rows'] = call_to_total_count_function;
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $data["total"] = call_to_total_count_function;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $data["per_page"] = 10;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = "<div class = 'pagination'>";
        $config['full_tag_close'] = "</div>";
        //$config['additional_param']  = 'serialize_form()';
        $config['div'] = '#div_to_load_result'; /* Here #content is the CSS selector for target DIV */
        //$config['js_rebind'] = "alert('it works !!'); "; /* if you want to bind extra js code */
        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->jquery_pagination->initialize($config);
        $html  =  $this->jquery_pagination->create_links();
        $html .= '<br>';
        //$this->table->function = 'htmlspecialchars';
        //$this->table->set_heading('Delivery','image','time','delivery','old');
        $html .= $this->table->generate($this->modelname->modelFunction( $limit ));

        echo $html;
    }


        // first time loading result in controller
function index()
    {
        $config['base_url'] = controllerFunction
        $config['total_rows'] = total_number_of_result;
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $data["total"] = total_number_of_result
        $data["per_page"] = 10;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = "<div class = 'pagination'>";
        $config['full_tag_close'] = "</div>";
        //$config['additional_param']  = 'serialize_form()';
        $config['div'] = '#div_to_load_result'; /* Here #content is the CSS selector for target DIV */
        //$config['js_rebind'] = "alert('it works !!'); "; /* if you want to bind extra js code */
        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->jquery_pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['html'] =  $this->jquery_pagination->create_links().'<br>'.$this->table->generate($this->modelname->modelFunction());

        $this->theme->view(path_of_view, $data);
    }
// now in view  add following line 
<div id="mygrid"><?php echo $html; ?></div>
```